# Android - Load images from external folder into array

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm new to android development and I have my way around drawables. I am now trying to achieve access to an external folder(from SD card) and load the images into an array of int so I could use them. However, after some research around S.O I still can't find something that can help me.

Currently I am putting images(*.jpg) from my Drawable folder and I have them in an array as follows:

```
int[] image = { R.drawable.location, R.drawable.diversity, R.drawable.classes, R.drawable.activities, R.drawable.sports, R.drawable.friends,
                    R.drawable.graduate};
```

How can I load images from an external folder into something similar like the array above? The problem here is with the images names. How will I actually get the image names when I load them from that external folder(assuming it contains only images)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just get the folder contents with File dir = new File(path);
String[] files = dir.list();

Comment: @matty357 But here the problem is it's not an int array which makes it impossible to use with my `setImageResource(image[index]);`

Answer (score 0):

following method will return you path of all image from your device , get these path , and use them to show image

```
 public ArrayList<String> getFilePaths()
        {


            Uri u = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI; 
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA}; 
            Cursor c = null;
            SortedSet<String> dirList = new TreeSet<String>();
            ArrayList<String> resultIAV = new ArrayList<String>();

             String[] directories = null; 
            if (u != null) 
            { 
                c = managedQuery(u, projection, null, null, null); 
            } 

            if ((c != null) && (c.moveToFirst())) 
            { 
                do 
                {
                    String tempDir = c.getString(0);
                    tempDir = tempDir.substring(0, tempDir.lastIndexOf("/"));
                    try{
                        dirList.add(tempDir);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                } 
                while (c.moveToNext());
                directories = new String[dirList.size()];
                dirList.toArray(directories);

            }

            for(int i=0;i<dirList.size();i++)
            {
                File imageDir = new File(directories[i]);
                File[] imageList = imageDir.listFiles();
                if(imageList == null)
                    continue;
                for (File imagePath : imageList) { 
                    try {

                            if(imagePath.isDirectory())
                            {
                                imageList = imagePath.listFiles();

                            }
                            if ( imagePath.getName().contains(".jpg")|| imagePath.getName().contains(".JPG")  
                                    || imagePath.getName().contains(".jpeg")|| imagePath.getName().contains(".JPEG")                                    
                                    || imagePath.getName().contains(".png") || imagePath.getName().contains(".PNG")
                                    || imagePath.getName().contains(".gif") || imagePath.getName().contains(".GIF")
                                    || imagePath.getName().contains(".bmp") || imagePath.getName().contains(".BMP")                         
            )
                            {



                                String path= imagePath.getAbsolutePath();
                            resultIAV.add(path);

                            }
                        }
                //  }
                catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return resultIAV;


        }
```